# Issue detecting collision between two div elements using Intersection Observer API in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, intersection-observer

I'm trying to detect a collision between two div elements using the Intersection Observer API in JavaScript, but it's not working as expected. The div elements have absolute positioning, and I want to detect when they intersect each other.

I tried to behave box2 as a root element and box1 as a observer, but it didn't work. It only works when I set root: null in options. Here, in the official documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

it is clearly stated that: A target element intersects either the device's viewport or a specified element. So, I want to set target element a specified element i.e. box2.

```js
  var box1 = document.querySelector(".box1");
  var box2 = document.querySelector(".box2");
    
  function handleIntersection(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
      console.log(entry.target);
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        console.log("Magnet element is intersecting with the target div: ", entry.target);
        // want to perform some action
      }
    });
  }
  
  var observerOptions = {
    root: box2,
    threshold: 0 // Adjust the threshold value as needed
  };
  
  var observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, observerOptions);
  
  observer.observe(box1);
```

```html
<div class="white-board">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.white-board{
    border: 3px solid grey;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 50px;
    height: 300px;
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.box1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
.box2{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the exact page you linked:

`root` -
The element that is used as the viewport for checking visibility of the target. Must be the ancestor of the target. Defaults to the browser viewport if not specified or if null.

Box2 does not have any children, there is no way this will work. For it to work, box1 should be inside box2.